# Cannot close UDP socket using dgram nodejs

Tags: node.js, sockets

I use nodejs to listen to data from UDP:

```js
const server = dgram.createSocket({type: "udp4", reuseAddr: true});
server.bind({address: config.udpIp, port: config.udpPort});

server.on("message", (msg, rinfo) => {
  console.log(`Mesage: ${msg}`);
 });

stop() {
     console.log('Stop UDP listener');
  server.close();
}
```

Note: node v6.10.3 on Linux Centos 6

But when I call stop() method, messages are still arriving my application.
Please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you provide more details about your code ? what is your registered function on message events ?

Comment: @ParhamAlvani updated

Comment: maybe when you close your socket you have some message in underline buffer and they send to you ? I mean they arrive before you closing socket.

Comment: It's probably the problem. Now my app stops receiving message. Thanks